# How compile assests sage9 theme with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have setup sage 9 theme with wordpress but need a help that how to compile the assests in wordpress

Comment: If you did 'npm install' you can build the assets with 'npm run build'!?

Comment: I tried with 'yarn build:production' and it works.

Comment: Good to here it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem, may helpful for others so sharing the link:
https://roots.io/sage/docs/theme-deployment/